How to check all columns has null value or not in particular row in Snowflake
I want to check  all columns has null value or not in particular row in Snowflake
EMP:
A   B   C
1   2   3
4   5   6
null    null    null

now I am checking like below:
select * from EMP where A is null and B is null and C is null;

Can some one help is there any alternative way to achieve this instead of A is null and B is null and C is null?

What do you mean by "alternative way"? What's wrong with your query? What improvement do you expect when changing it?

@JonasMetzler The query "A is null and B is null and C is null" is valid and working. And there is nothing wrong with searching for alternatives. For instance instead of explicitly listing all columns  COLAESCE(*)  can be used(handy for wide tables). One may say "irrelevant", somebody else can value generic approach and/or learn something new.

@LukaszSzozda I know that, wanted OP to explain what improvement they expect. Why not just let them answer?

A generic way to access all columns without specifying their names is to use * with a variable-length argument function. Example:
SELECT *, COALESCE(*) AS all_cols
FROM EMP
WHERE all_cols IS NULL;

Output:

Sidenote: If columns' data types differ they should be implicitly castable.

Extra: This pattern can be further extended for use case where not all columns are required:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE EMP(id INT, A INT, B INT, C INT)
AS
SELECT 1,1,2,3 UNION
SELECT 2,4,5,6 UNION
SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, NULL;

Skip id column with * EXCLUDE(id):
SELECT *, COALESCE(* EXCLUDE(id)) AS all_cols
FROM EMP
WHERE all_cols IS NULL;

Related: Wildcard filtering for functions

EDIT: Using ARRAY_CONSTRUCT_COMPACT for improved handling of different data types:
SELECT *, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT_COMPACT(*) AS all_cols
FROM EMP
WHERE all_cols = [];


does it work if columns have different datatypes?

@SalmanArshad For COALESCE data types must be the same or implicitly castable. For different data types ARRAY_COMPACT(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(*)) and comparison to [] can be used.

@LukaszSzozda Can be shortened to array_construct_compact(*) = []

Hi you can use  COALESCE to get rows which are having all the columns as Null.
select *   from EMP 
 where COALESCE(A,B,C) is null

